# PWA share_target accept all file

Tags: javascript, html, frontend, progressive-web-apps

I want allow my PWA to accept all possible file format, but "application/*" don't works (on file like "application/octet-stream" my PWA don't is into share menu:

```
"share_target": {
    "action": "/?pwa=share_target",
    "method": "POST",
    "enctype": "multipart/form-data",
    "params": {
      "files": [
        {
          "name": "file",
          "accept": [
            "image/*", "video/*", "audio/*", "application/*", "text/*", "font/*"
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```